# How to fix: roles is not defined (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, replit

I'm trying to add a role to a member when they join my server, here is the code I have:

The problem I'm getting is `"ReferenceError: roles is not defined"` can someone please help me solve this?

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    console.log("User " + member.user.username + " has joined the server!");
    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Javjajjaj");
    roles.add(role);
});
```

Comment: You never define `roles` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `roles` variable is never defined within your piece of code.

---

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", GuildMember => {
    // Logging when a GuildMember enters the Guild.
    console.log(`${GuildMember.user.tag} joined ${GuildMember.guild.name}!`);

    const Role = GuildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Javjajjaj"); // Finding the Role by name in the GuildMember's Guild.

    // Checking if the role exists.
    if (!Role) return console.error("Couldn't find the role!");
    // Trying to add the Role to the GuildMember and catching any error(s).
    GuildMember.roles.add(Role).catch(error => console.error(`Couldn't add the Role to the GuildMember. | ${error}`));
});
```